# Comparing strings in ISO format works

Tags: javascript

I was totally surprised when this worked:

```
'2018-01-14 04:09:00' < '2018-01-14 04:09:01' // true
'2018-01-14 04:09:00' < '2018-01-01 04:09:00' // false
```

Are comparisons on ISO formated time strings guranteed to work in javascript? Is there any docs on this? Is this new? Or is this supported even in old browsers like IE? I discovered this in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, it should work on JavaScript, Java, and probably most languages.  Just make sure you really have fixed width ISO format.

Comment: Wow absolutely amazing. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen I never knew that and I was doing javascript for years.

Comment: It is more important for something like SQLite, where dates are stored as text.  There, correct date comparisons rely on this behavior.

Comment: JavaScript compares strings based on lexicographic order, there is nothing surprising then :-P

Comment: Totally cool thanks muchly @leaf and @ Tim

Comment: There's no special treatment to ISO formated time strings. This is how string comparison works in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: The format is designed so that lexicographical string comparison can be used to compare dates. It's not new or special cased or otherwise magical.

Comment: Thanks @pvg for that clarification, so the underlying problem was that I didn't fully understand lexical.

Comment: Got it, thanks @AlekseyL. - so the docs are in the lexical-ness.

Comment: "a" < "b" < "bb" < "z" < "z11" < "z2"... As simple as a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks leaf that helps me a lot!